# Can't start screen at boot time

Tags: linux, sh, gnu-screen, init.d

I'm trying to create a script for rtorrent in order to start it at boot time. I've planed on use screen but it seems it doesn't work. Here is a simple script for testing I used:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: test
# Required-Start: $network $syslog
# Required-Stop: $network
# Default-Start: 2 3 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Description: Test script
### END INIT INFO

start() {
        echo "start"
        su -l myuser -c "screen -dmS cat cat"
}

stop() {
        echo "stop"
}

restart() {
        echo "restart"
        start
}

case $1 in
        start)
                start
        ;;
        stop)
                stop
        ;;
        restart)
                restart
        ;;
        *)
                echo "Usage: {start|stop|restart}" >&2
                exit 2
        ;;
esac
```

I can't get the screen back using `screen -r cat`. Same problem using dtach. Am I doing something wrong.

EDIT: I changed the script to start screen with a specified user. But, my echo doesn't appear when using service start/stop/reload. Why?

Comment: This would run `screen` as root. Are you perhaps trying to attach it as your user?

Comment: I am stupid. You are right.

Comment: Try using `crontab` with the `@reboot` time.